# checking if the given inputted word is a palindrome or not

Tags: python, algorithm, palindrome

```
a=raw_input("enter the word")
b=[str(letter) for letter in a]
c=b[::-1]
print c

if b==c:
    print ("it is a palindrome") 
else:
    print "it is not a palindrome"
```

this program works fine..just one question how do i modify it so that it prints nurses run as a palindrome. it is currently printing nursesrun as a palindrome. please help and suggest.
this code is for python 2.7 and please to improvise on this code only. thanks.

Comment: replace is not an argument. i like your idea but please give  the correct attribute and argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are better ways of doing this, this example shows an improvement (specifically) for your code. you can check for [`letter.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

```
b = [str(letter) for letter in a if letter.isalpha()]
```

and now the check would work.

Demo:

```
>>> x = "nurses run"
>>> b=[str(letter) for letter in x if letter.isalpha()]
>>> 
>>> b
['n', 'u', 'r', 's', 'e', 's', 'r', 'u', 'n']
>>> c = b[::-1]
>>> b == c
True
>>>
```

EDIT:

The code using `replace`:

```
x = x.replace(" ", "")

>>> x = "nurses run"
>>> x = x.replace(" ", "")
>>> x
'nursesrun'
```

Note that you would have to replace explicitly every single type this way.

Comment: +1 Might also do `letter.lower()`. And isn't that `str(...)` unneccesary?

Comment: @tobias_k Agreed. `lower()` might be an option based on the requirement. Also, `str()` is redundant.

Comment: lower is a function, not a property.

Comment: @karthikr can we replace " " with "" in the string?

Comment: so that the spaces are gone

Comment: Yes. that is an option too. But since you are iterating over the element anyways, the net effect is the same. NOte that `isalpha()` is just an example. You can filter by anything

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word == ''.join(reversed(word))

print is_palindrome('madam') #True
```